# images with borders not resizing correctly with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im using boostrap to create a responsive website and have come across a problem with images that contain borders.

When my page is maxed the images are fine but if i start reducing the width the columns resize as expected but part of the image is to big for the column and is clipped. The amount clipped equals the width of the border.  Is there a problem with bootstrap and images resizing with borders.

Heres my code

```HTML
<div class="container">
    <div class="row rowTopMargin">
        <div class="span6">
            <img class="ExampleTiles" src="img/FootPrints.jpg" alt="FootPrints carbon calculator" title="FootPrints Carbon Calculator" />
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <img class="ExampleTiles" src="img/EliseDesigns.jpg" alt="Elise Designs" title="Elise Designs Website" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row rowTopMargin rowBottomMargin">
        <div class="span6">
            <img class="ExampleTiles" src="img/TreatMe.jpg" alt="Treat Me At Home" title="Treat Me At Home Website" />
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <img class="ExampleTiles" src="img/TreatMe.jpg" alt="Treat Me At Home" title="Treat Me At Home Website" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the correct border[image]

And here is the clipped border.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so it seems that the problem is with the 100% width of the img.  Setting

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

moves the border inside the box and fixes the 100% problem